# @EventListener & IRequestCycle.getResponseBuilder.updateComponent not updating component

Tags: java, html, tapestry, event-listener

I am having a problem on my application, what I am trying to do is when ever someone changes the field `shopStatus` on the form to `Pass`, i want it to update my field `shopApprovalDate` to be mandatory. I am using the following event listener for this

```
@EventListener(targets="shopStatus", events="onchange")
public void onLicenseStatusChange(IRequestCycle cycle) {
    cycle.getResponseBuilder().updateComponent("shopStatus");
    cycle.getResponseBuilder().updateComponent("shopApprovalDateRequired");
    cycle.getResponseBuilder().updateComponent("shopApprovalDate");

}
```

this is the html that I am using for this

```
<td valign="center" align="left" class="rightTD" height="30" >
         <span jwcid="@If" condition="ognl:company.shopStatus == @valueobject.ShopStatus@Pass" renderTag="literal:false">
            <input jwcid="shopApprovalDateRequired@CustomDatePicker" disabled="ognl:disabled || isShopApprovalDateDisabled()"
            value="ognl:company.shopApprovalDate" displayName="message:company.shopApprovalDate" validators="validators:maxDateToday,required" />
         </span>
         <span jwcid="@Else" renderTag="literal:false">
            <input jwcid="shopApprovalDate@CustomDatePicker" disabled="ognl:disabled || isShopApprovalDateDisabled()"
            value="ognl:company.shopApprovalDate" displayName="message:company.shopApprovalDate" validators="validators:maxDateToday" />
         </span>
        </td>
```

The thing is that, if I change the `shopStatus` to `Pass` nothing happens, but if i save the page and reload the page, then the `shopApprovalDate` is set to mandatory so the html code is working, it is like the `@EventListener` is not updating `shopApprovalDate` when `shopStatus` is changed! I have debugged through the code and it is hitting the listener but nothing is happeneing

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: looks like an old version of tapestry, 4.?

Comment: tapestry-framework-4.1.6, why does that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you need to call an update on something that calls the @IF @Else and not the actual component itself

If you add a  outside the @If @Else and call that in the Event Listener this should work then like so

The `<div>`

```
<div jwcid="licenceAuthRequiredDiv@Any">
<td valign="center" align="left" class="rightTD" height="30" >
     <span jwcid="@If" condition="ognl:company.shopStatus == @valueobject.ShopStatus@Pass" renderTag="literal:false">
        <input jwcid="shopApprovalDateRequired@CustomDatePicker" disabled="ognl:disabled || isShopApprovalDateDisabled()"
        value="ognl:company.shopApprovalDate" displayName="message:company.shopApprovalDate" validators="validators:maxDateToday,required" />
     </span>
     <span jwcid="@Else" renderTag="literal:false">
        <input jwcid="shopApprovalDate@CustomDatePicker" disabled="ognl:disabled || isShopApprovalDateDisabled()"
        value="ognl:company.shopApprovalDate" displayName="message:company.shopApprovalDate" validators="validators:maxDateToday" />
     </span>
    </td>
</div>
```

The event listener

```
@EventListener(targets="licensingStatus", events="onchange")
public void onLicenseStatusChange(IRequestCycle cycle){
    cycle.getResponseBuilder().updateComponent("licenceAuthRequiredDiv");
}
```